# How to add the returnURL to a SAML request?

Tags: saml, service-provider

Problem: an SP site xyz.com/A gets a request for a resource xyz.com/B requiring authentication. A SAML request with relay_state=xyz.com/B gets sent to the iDP. The user gets redirected to the iDP site through SAML/SSO then onto idp.com.

I want to implement a link that allows the user to cancel his request for xyz.com/B and simply return him back to where he was browsing at xyz.com/A. Because there was a SAML redirect, I can't use the referer header at idp.com to find out where the user came from. Ideally I want to send the returnURL=xyz.com/A inside my SAML request.

So the question is is there such a way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a standard SAML way you could achieve this.  You would likely need to rely on custom extensions (such as additional query string parameters) to tell the IdP where to go on cancel.

Alternatively (and not so elegant - but practical) you could use JavaScript to send the user back a couple steps in the history?  E.g.:

```
window.history.go(-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The IDP can return SAML response to SP. In the SAML response, you can use Status element to indicate that the user has cancelled the authentication process. As the top-level status code, you can use urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:Responder. You can use your own status code as the the second-level status code.